Streamlit does not support nltk GUI in its deployment environment
Chat Gpt answer:- It seems like the NLTK download function is trying to open a graphical interface which doesn't work well in headless environments like Streamlit. To fix this, you can avoid using the graphical downloader and instead manually handle the download of NLTK data in your script. This can be done by specifying the download directory.
import streamlit as st
import pickle
import string
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

import os

# Ensure nltk resources are downloaded
nltk_data_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/nltk_data')
if not os.path.exists(nltk_data_dir):
    os.makedirs(nltk_data_dir)

try:
    nltk.data.find('corpora/stopwords.zip')
except LookupError:
    nltk.download('stopwords', download_dir=nltk_data_dir)

try:
    nltk.data.find('tokenizers/punkt.zip')
except LookupError:
    nltk.download('punkt', download_dir=nltk_data_dir)

nltk.data.path.append(nltk_data_dir)
ps = PorterStemmer()

def transform_text(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

    y = []
    for i in text:
        if i.isalnum():
            y.append(i)
    text = y[:]
    y.clear()

    for i in text:
        if i not in stopwords.words('english') and i not in string.punctuation:
            y.append(i)

    text = y[:]
    y.clear()

    for i in text:
        y.append(ps.stem(i))

    return " ".join(y)

tfidf = pickle.load(open('vectorizer.pkl', 'rb'))
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

st.title("Email/SMS Spam Classifier")

input_sms = st.text_area("Enter the message")

if st.button('Predict'):
    # 1. preprocess
    transformed_sms = transform_text(input_sms)
    # 2. vectorize
    vector_input = tfidf.transform([transformed_sms])
    # 3. predict
    result = model.predict(vector_input)[0]
    # 4. display
    if result == 1:
        st.header("Spam")
    else:
        st.header("Not Spam")

File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 589, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/sms-spam-detection/app.py", line 18, in <module>
    nltk.download('stopwords', download_dir=nltk_data_dir)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 823, in download
    show(
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 769, in show
    print_to( 

Above is the error im getting in streamlit
Git Hub repo link:- https://github.com/milikotnala/sms-spam-detection
I made some changes
by adding the below block of code but the error stays same
import os

# Ensure nltk resources are downloaded
nltk_data_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/nltk_data')
if not os.path.exists(nltk_data_dir):
    os.makedirs(nltk_data_dir)

try:
    nltk.data.find('corpora/stopwords.zip')
except LookupError:
    nltk.download('stopwords', download_dir=nltk_data_dir)

try:
    nltk.data.find('tokenizers/punkt.zip')
except LookupError:
    nltk.download('punkt', download_dir=nltk_data_dir)

nltk.data.path.append(nltk_data_dir)

